# Comparing record types with LINQ in C#

Tags: c#, linq, record

I am trying to implement record types to make comparing less complex. But I ran into issues comparing records to each other. I expect records to be equal when properties are equal to each other but this isn't the case in my code..

I have a record class called `MyAlarm` with some properties. It inherits from the interface `IAlarm` which is empty.

```cs
public record MyAlarm : IAlarm
{
    public int Prop1 { get; init; }
    public int Prop2 { get; init; }
}
```

A class called `VisibleAlarm` has the IAlarm as property plus some extra data.

```cs
public record VisibleAlarm
{
    public IAlarm InternalAlarm { get; init; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

In a class called `AlarmService` the VisibleAlarms are listed and updated when needed. This service has a List of visible alarms.

Further in this alarm service the list is checked if an alarm already exists depending on the IAlarm property. I have tried two methods:

```cs
public class AlarmService
{
    private List<VisibleAlarm> _alarms = new();

    // ... Other code that handles alarm stuff

    private VisibleAlarm GetExistingAlarm1(IAlarm alarm)
    {
        return _alarms.FirstOrDefault(a => a.InternalAlarm == alarm);
    }

    private VisibleAlarm GetExistingAlarm2(IAlarm alarm)
    {
        foreach (var existingAlarm in _alarms)
        {
            if (existingAlarm.InternalAlarm == alarm)
            {
                return existingAlarm;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When debugging the code I see that the record properties of the existingAlarm.InternalAlarm and the given alarm match but still the `GetExistingAlarm` methods return both false. Am i missing something or must I implement a IEqualityComparer because of interface IAlarm?

Cheers

Comment: I would suggest creating a minimal reproducible example. I.e. create two alarms with the same properties and verify that they are equal when compared. That helps you isolate the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your line of code:

```
return _alarms.FirstOrDefault(a => a.InternalAlarm == alarm);
```

the `a.InternalAlarm == alarm` is calling `operator==` rather than `object.Equals()` to do the comparison.

You can fix this by changing the code to:

```
return _alarms.FirstOrDefault(a => a.InternalAlarm.Equals(alarm));
```

The following program demonstrates the difference:

```
using System;

static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        MyAlarm ma1 = new MyAlarm { Prop1 = 1, Prop2 = 2 };
        MyAlarm ma2 = new MyAlarm { Prop1 = 1, Prop2 = 2 };
        
        VisibleAlarm va1 = new VisibleAlarm { InternalAlarm = ma1, Message = "message" };
        VisibleAlarm va2 = new VisibleAlarm { InternalAlarm = ma2, Message = "message" };

        Console.WriteLine(ma1 == ma2); // True
        Console.WriteLine(va1 == va2); // True
        Console.WriteLine(va1.InternalAlarm == va2.InternalAlarm); // False
        Console.WriteLine(va1.InternalAlarm.Equals(va2.InternalAlarm)); // True
    }

    public interface IAlarm
    {
        int Prop1 { get; }
        int Prop2 { get; }
    }

    public record MyAlarm : IAlarm
    {
        public int Prop1 { get; init; }
        public int Prop2 { get; init; }
    }

    public record VisibleAlarm
    {
        public IAlarm InternalAlarm { get; init; }
        public string Message       { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
True
True
False
True
```

The reason this isn't working for you is because `InternalAlarm` is of type `IAlarm` and not `MyAlarm`. If you change the type to `MyAlarm`, you'll get the comparison as `true` rather than `false`.

This is because `IAlarm` does not define an `operator==` (note: such an operator would be static).

Comment: That was surprisingly easy (and foolish of me). It works with the .Equals for both methods.